# can't use get() method in query builder yajra datatables Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

[image]
I have datatable that show user task. I've created the filter for KPI table to show specific KPI (Yes or No). The problem is when I use get() method I can't filter with the dropdown, and if I replace get() using latest() `$data = Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->uid)->latest();`or remove it `$data = Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->uid);`, my datatable can't sorting data with sort button in table head. here is my code

My controller

```
public function MyTask(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()) {

            $data = Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->uid)->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                   ...
                })->addColumn('target_selesai', function ($row) {
                  ...
                })->addColumn('kpi', function ($row) {
                   ...
                })->addColumn('progress', function ($row) {
                   ...
                })->addColumn('status', function ($row) {
                   ...
                })->filter(function ($instance) use ($request) {
                    if ($request->get('kpi') == '0' || $request->get('kpi') == '1') {
                        $instance->where('kpi', $request->get('kpi'));
                    }
                    if (!empty($request->get('search'))) {
                        $instance->where(function ($w) use ($request) {
                            $search = $request->get('search');
                            $w->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                ->orWhere('target_selesai', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                ->orWhere('target', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                ->orWhere('realisasi', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
                        });
                    }
                })->rawColumns(['action', 'progress', 'status'])
                ->make(true);
        }

        return view('task.mytask');
    }
```

My view

```
 var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
                paging: true,
                info: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [{
                        "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        "className": "text-center",
                    },

                ],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('my.task') }}",
                    data: function(d) {
                        d.kpi = $('#filter-kpi').val(),
                            d.search = $('input[type="search"]').val()
                    }
                },
                // a
                columns: [{
                     ...
                ]
            });
   $('#filter-kpi').change(function() {
                table.draw();
            });
```

Is there something wrong in my code? Or I should use other method? thanks in advance

Comment: You need to  make your query before the `get()` method.

Comment: what do u mean query? Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->uid) is not a query?

Comment: After the `Post::where('user_id', Auth::user()->uid)->get()` you use the where clause `$instance->where……`

Comment: can you please give me example for my case? because I can't understand it